# Why is one of my child components able to get handleClick() but the others are not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

**PROBLEM**

I am swapping components based on state in Dashboard(parent) component and passing props to all of them. When I log in using wholesaler the app is running without problems but when i log in with retailer account the app return

> TypeError: this.props.handleClick is not a function

when i click on a button-handleClick() -> switch components through handleClick which changes state

My components are almost identical and i have no idea where this is coming from.

Thank you in advance! :)

**Files**:

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Retailers } from './_components/Retailers'
import { Locations } from './_components/Locations'
import { Products } from './_components/Products'

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      chosenRetailerId: null,
      chosenLocationId: null,
      mountComponent: ''
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    switch (this.props.user.type) {
      case 'wholesaler':
        this.setState({ mountComponent: "retailers" })
        break;
      case 'retailer':
        this.setState({ mountComponent: "locations" })
        break;
      case 'location':
        this.setState({ mountComponent: "products" })
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  handleClick(id, shouldMountComponent) { 
    switch (shouldMountComponent) {
      case 'locations':
        this.setState({
          mountComponent: shouldMountComponent,
          chosenRetailerId: id
        })
        break;
      case 'products':
        this.setState({
          mountComponent: shouldMountComponent,
          chosenLocationId: id
        })
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props
    const { chosenLocationId, chosenRetailerId, mountComponent } = this.state

    return (
      <div className="dashboard">
        {user.type === 'wholesaler' &&
          <div className="wholesaler">
            <h1>Wholesaler</h1>
            <h3>{user._id}</h3>
            {this.state.mountComponent === 'retailers' &&
            <Retailers mountComponent={mountComponent} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
            }
            {this.state.mountComponent === 'locations' &&
            <Locations retailerId={chosenRetailerId} locationId={chosenLocationId} mountComponent={mountComponent} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
            }            
            {this.state.mountedComponent === 'products' &&
            <Products locationId={chosenLocationId} mountComponent={mountComponent}/>
            }
          </div>
        }
        {user.type === 'retailer' &&
          <div className="retailers">
            <h1>Retailer {user._id}</h1>
            <Locations locationId={chosenLocationId}/>
          </div>
        }
        {user.type === 'location' &&
          <div className="locations">
            <h1>Location {user._id}</h1>
            <Products />
          </div>
        }
        <p>You're logged in with React & JWT!!</p>
        <p>
          <Link to="/login">Logout</Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { authentication } = state
  const { user } = authentication

  return {
      user
  }
}

const connectedDashboard = connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard)
export { connectedDashboard as Dashboard }
```

**Retailers.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Retailers extends Component {
    state = {
        retailers: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { user } = this.props

        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token }
        }

        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/retailers/by-wholesaler/${user._id}`, requestOptions)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    retailers: result
                })
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { retailers } = this.state

        return (
            <div className="retailers">
                {retailers.map((retailer, index) =>
                <button key={index} onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(retailer._id, 'locations')}>{retailer.name}</button>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { authentication } = state
    const { user } = authentication

    return { user }
}

const connectedRetailers = connect(mapStateToProps)(Retailers)
export { connectedRetailers as Retailers }
```

**Locations.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Locations extends Component {
    state = {
        locations: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { user } = this.props

        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token }
        }

        const retailerId = (user.type === 'retailer') ? user._id : this.props.retailerId
        console.log(retailerId)

        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/locations/by-retailer/${retailerId}`, requestOptions)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    locations: result
                })
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { locations } = this.state

        return (
            <div className="locations">
                {locations.map((location, index) =>
                <button key={index} onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(location._id, 'products')}>{location.name}</button>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { authentication } = state
    const { user } = authentication

    return { user }
}

const connectedLocations = connect(mapStateToProps)(Locations)
export { connectedLocations as Locations }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `handleCLick` to `location` as a prop. You do that in you wholesaler case (passing it to the retailer component), but not when using the Locations component

Comment: I did not notice i am using switch case... thank you so much for opening my eyes :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass `handleClick` as a prop :)

```
<Retailers handleClick={this.handleClick} />
<Locations handleClick={this.handleClick} />
```

So prop is undefined and you can't call it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `locations.map` function in your Locations.js.
Your are passing a so called `thisArg` to the map function, so it is no longer using the right context.

This should work:

```
<div className="locations">
    {locations.map((location, index) =>
        <button key={index} onClick={() =>
            this.props.handleClick(location._id, 'products')}>
            {location.name}
        </button>
     )}
</div>
```

Also, think about using the `uuid` package for your iteration keys. Now you are using an index and that will not be unique if you do so in another iteration too (not the case yet so).

Comment: still not working :( thank you for trying to help though :)

Comment: DSCH is right, you have a Location Component where the event is not passed.